# How to make dialog form with Vuetify in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using the VueJS Vuetify framework and I need to open a dialog form - that gets imported as a component template - from another template.Once the ChangeMealDialog button in Meals.vue got clicked, the Modal should open. Here is my setup:

Parent Component Meals.vue

```
<template>
<div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">

        <v-simple-table>
            <template v-slot:default>
                <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <th class="text-left">Days</th>
                        <th class="text-left">Meals</th>
                        <th class="text-left">Calories</th>

                        <th class="text-right">
                            <router-link to="/addmeal">
                                <v-btn color="primary" small right>
                                    Add Meal
                                </v-btn>
                            </router-link>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="normalCalorie">
                    <tr v-for="meal in meals.meals" :key="meal._id">
                        <td class="text-left">{{ meal.date }}</td>
                        <td class="text-left">{{ meal.text }}</td>
                        <td class="text-left">{{ meal.numOfCalories }}</td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <ChangeMealDialog ref="dialogRef">
                                <template @click="dialog = true" slot="dialogActivetor">
                                    <v-btn slot="dialogActivator" color="primary" @click="$refs.dialogRef.setDefaultTable()" dark fab small right>
                                        <v-icon small>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
                                    </v-btn>
                                </template>
                            </ChangeMealDialog>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </template>
        </v-simple-table>
    </v-app>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import {
    fetchMeals,
    deleteMeal,
} from '@/api';
import ChangeMealDialog from './ChangeMealDialog';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            dialog: false,
            meals: [],
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.getMeals();
    },
    methods: {
        async getMeals() {
            this.meals = await fetchMeals();
        },

        async deleteMeal() {
            await deleteMeal(this.meal._id)
        },
    },
    components: {
        ChangeMealDialog,
    }
}
</script>
```

Child Component ChangeMealDialog.vue

```
<template>
<div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
        <v-row justify="center">
            <v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent max-width="600px">
                <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                    <v-btn color="primary" dark v-bind="attrs" v-on="on" fab small right>
                        <v-icon small>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
                    </v-btn>
                </template>
                <v-card>
                    <v-toolbar color="primary" dark flat>
                        <v-toolbar-title>Change Meal</v-toolbar-title>
                        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                    </v-toolbar>
                    <v-card-text>
                        <v-container>
                            <v-row>
                                <v-col cols="12">
                                    <v-text-field label="Date*" v-model="meal.date" required></v-text-field>
                                </v-col>
                                <v-col cols="12">
                                    <v-text-field label="Time*" v-model="meal.time" required></v-text-field>
                                </v-col>
                                <v-col cols="12">
                                    <v-text-field label="Text*" v-model="meal.text" required></v-text-field>
                                </v-col>
                                <v-col cols="12">
                                    <v-text-field label="Calorie*" v-model="meal.calorie" required></v-text-field>
                                </v-col>
                            </v-row>
                        </v-container>
                    </v-card-text>
                    <v-card-actions>
                        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                        <v-tooltip left>
                            <ApproveDialog @approve="updateMeal">
                                <v-btn @click="dialog = false" fab dark small color="warning">
                                </v-btn>
                            </ApproveDialog>
                            Save
                        </v-tooltip>
                        <v-btn color="primary" text @click="dialog = false">Close</v-btn>
                    </v-card-actions>
                </v-card>
            </v-dialog>
        </v-row>
    </v-app>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            dialog: false,
        }
    },
    props: [
        'meal',
    ],
    methods: {
        async updateMeal() {
            await this.$store.dispatch('updateMeal', this.meal._id);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

How to open the dialog?

Child Component Approve.vue

```
<template>
<v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="400px">
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-btn color="error" dark v-bind="attrs" v-on="on" fab x-small right>
            <v-icon small>mdi-delete</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
    </template>
    <v-card>
        <v-card-title class="headline">Are you sure?</v-card-title>
        <v-card-actions>
            <v-btn @click="close">
                No
            </v-btn>
            <v-spacer />
            <v-btn @click="submit">
                Yes
            </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
</v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            dialog: false,
        };
    },
    props: ['id'],
    methods: {
        submit() {
            this.$emit('approve', this.id);
            this.close();
        },
        close() {
            this.dialog = false;
            this.$emit('dialClose');
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

How to open the dialog?

Answer (score 0):

In your Meals.vue

```
<td class="text-right">
    <ChangeMealDialog />
</td>
```

And in your ChangeMealDialog.vue

```
<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="dialog" width="600">
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
      <v-btn
        v-on="on"
      >
        <v-icon left>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </template>
    <v-card>
         // form components
    </v-card>
</template>
```

Add `dialog:false` in your ChangeMealDialog.vue data property. You can follow the same for Approve button. Also in card title instead of toolbar you can make use of `v-card-title`. Read docs for more information.

Comment: Can you elaborate what doesn't work or update your code so I can see the error.

Answer (score 0):

Parent Component

```
<template>
<div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">

        <v-simple-table>
            <template v-slot:default>
                <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <th class="text-left">Days</th>
                        <th class="text-left">Meals</th>
                        <th class="text-left">Calories</th>

                        <th class="text-right">
                            <router-link to="/addmeal">
                                <v-btn color="primary" small right>
                                    Add Meal
                                </v-btn>
                            </router-link>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="normalCalorie">
                    <tr v-for="meal in meals.meals" :key="meal._id">
                        <td class="text-left">{{ meal.date }}</td>
                        <td class="text-left">{{ meal.text }}</td>
                        <td class="text-left">{{ meal.numOfCalories }}</td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <ChangeMealDialog />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </template>
        </v-simple-table>
    </v-app>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import {
    fetchMeals,
    deleteMeal,
} from '@/api';
import ChangeMealDialog from './ChangeMealDialog';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            meals: [],
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.getMeals();
    },
    methods: {
        async getMeals() {
            this.meals = await fetchMeals();
            console.log(this.meals);
        },

        async deleteMeal() {
            await deleteMeal(this.meal._id)
        },
    },
    components: {
        ChangeMealDialog,
    }
}
</script>
```

Child Component

```
<template>
<v-dialog v-model="dialog" width="600">
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
        <v-btn v-on="on">
            <v-icon left>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
    </template>

    <v-card>
        <v-card color="primary" dark flat>
            <v-card-title>Change Meal</v-card-title>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        </v-card>
        <v-card-text>
            <v-container>
                <v-row>
                    <v-col cols="12">
                        <v-text-field label="Date*" v-model="meal.date" required></v-text-field>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="12">
                        <v-text-field label="Time*" v-model="meal.time" required></v-text-field>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="12">
                        <v-text-field label="Text*" v-model="meal.text" required></v-text-field>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="12">
                        <v-text-field label="Calorie*" v-model="meal.calorie" required></v-text-field>
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>
            </v-container>
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-tooltip left>
                <ApproveDialog />
            </v-tooltip>
            <v-btn color="primary" text @click="dialog = false">Close</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
</v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {

        }
    },
    props: [
        'meal',
    ],
    methods: {
        async updateMeal() {
            await this.$store.dispatch('updateMeal', this.meal._id);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```